# Neo4j auto indexes - making them permanently stay on

Tags: neo4j

I have neo4j running as a windows service. when I restart my machine the auto indexing is not turned on.

```
neo4j-sh (0)$ eval db.index().getNodeAutoIndexer().isEnabled()
```

returns false

I have to run

```
neo4j-sh (0)$ eval db.index().getNodeAutoIndexer().setEnabled(true)
```

Every time I start the service.

I have the following in my config file

```
node_auto_indexing=true
node_keys_indexable=EmailAddress,Identifier,PostIdentifier,UserIdentifier
```

and these are the keys that become indexable when I `setEnabled(true)`

How do I configure the service so I don't have to enable the index at every start up?

Comment: Have you tried to actually index one entity? I think the indexes are created lazily.

Comment: Thanks @PeterNeubauer Could you elaborate on what you mean? I have a whole bunch of tests that test creation of all of the node types in my graph. When the nodeAutoIndexer is off, they all fail, when it's on they pass. These tests create nodes and they look up other nodes via indexes.

Comment: Are all indexes created lazily? how about non auto indexes?

Answer (score 2):

Per Peter Neubauer's comment, that indexes are created lazily.  So you have to create at least one entity (Node or Relationship) that contains at least one of your indexable properties. IMHO, this could be considered a bug in how indexes are managed. It's possible that you might want to issue a Cypher query on an index before the index has been lazily created. This query will result in an error since the index does not exist. But what you probably expected was an empty result set.  The fact that an error occurs actually leaks a bit of the index implementation to the caller.

In fact, I think I'll open an issue on this ;-)

Comment: Can you post a link to the issue so I can monitor it.

Comment: +1, please provide a console.neo4j.org testcase for easy recreation :)